# Mongo FIND Query to return Collections where Two Of Document's Fields Contain The Same Values (Were One is an Array)

Tags: mongodb

Lets say I have a collection called Messages and a message can have multiple parents which can be found by checking if the message_id is in the parent_id array, where the parent_id is an array.

```
{
   message_id : 22,
   parent_id: [22,11],
}
```

How would I create a mongo query to find that?

Right now I have the following but it fails:

```
db.messages.find({this.message_id: { $in: this.parent_id}})
```

Comment: This is definitely not a duplicate of the "MongoDB Aggregation - match if value in array" . That question is asking about aggregation. I am referring to mongo find queries. They are two completely different queries in mongodb .

Answer (score 0):

As you probably know mongo db does not support joins, I recommend you to do this at application level, using mongo shell you could run something like this.

```
//Get the message in which you are interested to get their parents
var child = db.messages.findOne({message_id: 22});
//Go with the array to search the parents.
db.messages.find({message_id : { $in :  child.parent_id }});
```

I think you need to do in two steps, unless somebody knows a more elegant solution.